# How to type not ASCII charecters in PyQt4 without getting error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, pyqt, pyqt4

I Want To Create Fuel calculator in python.PyQt4 and i have to type Not ASCII Characters and when i run code my characters turns to this :

[image]

is there any solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("FUEL CALCULATOR")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,400,300)
        self.cb = QComboBox(self)
        self.cb.addItem("რეგულარი")
        self.cb.addItem("ევრო რეგულარი")
        self.cb.addItem("პრემიუმი")
        self.cb.addItem("სუპერი")
        self.cb.addItem("დიზელი")
        self.cb.move(150,80)
        self.lbl_1 = QLabel("Enter Litre:>", self)
        self.lbl_1.move(50,120)
        self.button_1 = QPushButton("Calculate", self)
        self.button_1.move(150,160)
        self.text_box_1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text_box_1.move(150,120)
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        self.show()
    def calculate(self):
        sauce = urllib.urlopen("WEBSITE/NAME").read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
        for paragraph in soup.find_all('div', style_="width: 40%;float: left;"):
            print(paragraph.text)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If this is Python 2, I think you'll have to use Unicode literals, e.g. `u'abc'` instead of `'abc'`.

Comment: this is python2.7

Comment: you can try: `self.cb.addItem(u"რეგულარი")`

Comment: @Norrius want to make it a real answer? I just parrotted ;)

Comment: Drop the reload(sys)/setdefaultencoding as well.  That just hides problems.  See [Why sys.setdefaultencoding() will break code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).  The errors you got before adding that are *why* you should be using Unicode strings.  Switch to Python 3 which has better support for Unicode.  Python 2 support ends next year.